# Gulp web server hanging after pressing Ctrl+C

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am using gulp to run a server to serve my static assets. When I try to terminate gulp by pressing Ctrl+C, nothing happens. I have to manually find the pid of the gulp process and kill it. Here is the relevant code:

```
gulp.task 'default', ->
  runSequence(
    ...
    'server'
  )
  return

gulp.task 'server', ->
  PORT = 8090
  gulp.src('./dist')
    .pipe(webserver(
      livereload: true
      open: true
      port: PORT
    ))
  return
```

Comment: same here.  ever figure this out?